# What is the difference between the addEventListener API for "mouseenter" /"mouseleave" and React's onMouseEnter/onMouseLeave?

Tags: reactjs

What is the difference between using the addEventListener API in the element reference and using the property of these events already built into the React element? Is there any difference in performance from one mode to another? Would one way be more certain than the other?

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export const Component = () => {
  const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    divRef?.current.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
      //...
    });

    divRef?.current.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      //...
    });
  });

  return <div 
    onMouseEnter={() => console.log('on mouse enter react')} 
    onMouseLeave={() => console.log('on mouse leave react')}
  />;
};
```

Comment: I'm not going to answer your question, but unless you have a really good reason to use a custom listener (like bubbling options or count) then I don't see why you're asking the question. Mounting your own listener would just make things complicated and make your state more shaky.

Comment: This is explained in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html and https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html in summary, React wrapped the events api to make events work exactly the same across all browsers.